# RegEx Extract in DataStudio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am in DataStudio and trying to extract individual blog posts (we have multiple regions).

I want to extract everything between `/article/` and `?`

- not all instances have `?` (screenshot below)

I've managed to do the first part but not the second: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, '/article/(.*)')`

Example url string: `/au/article/how-to-clear-skin-in-4-steps/?sc_eh=0c375f5a122591491&sc_src=email_1`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have not provided a screenshot as you claim. About your problem: How about extracting everything that is not a `?`: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, '/article/([^?]*)')`

Comment: As Michi says, it seems your attached screenshot didn't get included properly.

I'd agree, too on their response - escape the special characters and you should be away! https://regex101.com/r/Firqzs/1

Comment: @Michi thank you very much! That worked perfectly. 

And apparently i dont have enough karma/ status to post screenshots so thank you again for working around that issue.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference adding an answer based on the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) by [Michi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166035/regex-extract-in-datastudio#comment116984364_66166035) in the comments as well as an additional [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) that replaces the `-` with   (a space) and removes the last `/`:

### 1) Extract everything between `/article/` and `?`

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, "/article/([^\\?]+)")
```

### 2) Replacing `-` with   (a space) and removing the last `/`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Landing Page, "/article/([^\\?]+)"), "[-/]", " ")
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4a8d7ac6-9634-40af-bf09-a0178b3a4db3) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]